# What is the Intel CPU feature code for Quick Sync?

Tags: macos, cpu, intel-graphics, terminal.app

I have an Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4980HQ CPU @ 2.80GHz, which I know supports Intel's Quick Sync.

I'm running the following command in the macOS Terminal to get all the CPU features:

```
sysctl -n machdep.cpu.features
```

I get this list of feature codes:

> FPU VME DE PSE TSC MSR PAE MCE CX8 APIC SEP MTRR PGE MCA CMOV PAT
>   PSE36 CLFSH DS ACPI MMX FXSR SSE SSE2 SS HTT TM PBE SSE3 PCLMULQDQ
>   DTES64 MON DSCPL VMX SMX EST TM2 SSSE3 FMA CX16 TPR PDCM SSE4.1 SSE4.2
>   x2APIC MOVBE POPCNT AES PCID XSAVE OSXSAVE SEGLIM64 TSCTMR AVX1.0
>   RDRAND F16C

What code (if any) in the above list identifies the Quick Sync feature?

Thanks

Comment: I don't think you'll find one because Quick Sync isn't really part of the x86 CPU. It's more related to the (integrated) GPU (technically, it's separate, but I think it's usually exposed by the graphics driver).

Comment: Thanks Bob. Looking at the macOS GPU info, I don't think its being explicitly listed there either. Hmm.Maybe the system lists videotoolbox encode ability somewhere else. I'm trying to get it via the Terminal to help a script I have which calls different ffmpeg encoders based on the systems ability to use videotoolbox.

Comment: For now I'm using a command which I found here:

https://www.jamf.com/jamf-nation/discussions/17512/reporting-on-graphics-card-or-gpu-hardware-installed-on-mac-clients

`system_profiler SPDisplaysDataType | awk -F': ' '/Chipset Model/ {print $2}' | tail -1`

Then if it returns anything with "Intel", its currently assumed VideoToolBox (Quick Sync) encoding is available.

Comment: You should add that as a self-answer (scroll to the bottom of the page).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should check the lisf of this link:
https://ark.intel.com/Search/FeatureFilter?productType=processors&QuickSyncVideo=true
if your cpu in this list, you have Quick Synx feartures on your cpu

Also intell defined cpu features code's meaning here below

1. vme: Virtual 8086 mode enhancements
2. de: Debugging Extensions (CR4.DE)
3. pse: Page Size Extensions (4MB memory pages)
4. tsc: Time Stamp Counter (RDTSC)
5. msr: Model-Specific Registers (RDMSR, WRMSR)
6. pae: Physical Address Extensions (support for more than 4GB of RAM)
7. mce: Machine Check Exception
8. cx8: CMPXCHG8 instruction (64-bit compare-and-swap)
9. apic: Onboard APIC
10. sep: SYSENTER/SYSEXIT
11. mtrr: Memory Type Range Registers
12. pge: Page Global Enable (global bit in PDEs and PTEs)
13. mca: Machine Check Architecture
14. cmov: CMOV instructions (conditional move) (also FCMOV)
15. pat: Page Attribute Table
16. pse36: 36-bit PSEs (huge pages)
17. pn: Processor serial number
18. clflush: Cache Line Flush instruction
19. dts: Debug Store (buffer for debugging and profiling instructions)
20. acpi: ACPI via MSR (temperature monitoring and clock speed modulation)
21. mmx: Multimedia Extensions
22. fxsr: FXSAVE/FXRSTOR, CR4.OSFXSR
23. sse: Intel SSE vector instructions
24. sse2: SSE2
25. ss: CPU self snoop
26. ht: Hyper-Threading
27. tm: Automatic clock control (Thermal Monitor)
28. ia64: Intel Itanium Architecture 64-bit (not to be confused with Intel's 64-30. bit x86 architecture with flag x86-64 or "AMD64" bit indicated by flag lm)
29. pbe: Pending Break Enable (PBE# pin) wakeup support
30. fpu: Onboard FPU (floating point support)

you can check following link to get more info from answers https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/43539/what-do-the-flags-in-proc-cpuinfo-mean

regards

Comment: Brilliant list, thanks so much Faruk. It doesn't look like Quick Sync is exposed by any of those flags, but thats a super useful list. I do know that my CPU has the ability, but (I should have written in the opening question), I want the ability to determine whether a system has the ability to use Quick Sync (videotoolbox) via a Terminal command to set a variable in a script I have.

Answer (score 2):

For now I'm using a command which I found [here](https://www.jamf.com/jamf-nation/discussions/17512/reporting-on-graphics-card-or-gpu-hardware-installed-on-mac-clients) to check for an Intel GPU:

```
system_profiler SPDisplaysDataType | awk -F': ' '/Chipset Model/ {print $2}' | tail -1
```

If it returns anything with the text "Intel", its currently assumed VideoToolBox (Quick Sync) encoding is available.

Answer (score 0):

I now have a different method which uses the ffmpeg cli. It tests the h264_videotoolbox hardware accelerated encoder. If the test returns 'success' then I know the system supports the hardware accelerated h264 encoding:

```
ffmpeg -v fatal -y -t 1 -f lavfi -i color=black:1920x1080 -c:v h264_videotoolbox -f null - && echo "success"
```